# Redirect to web app connection denied X-Frame-Options

Tags: node.js, url, redirect

I have just bought a domain and configured it to redirect to my server ip address when i google the site domain i get "Connection Denied" in the console developer i find this:

```
A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at (my ip address) was set without the `SameSite` attribute. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.
(my domain) Refused to display '(my ip address)' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.
```

Searching around i have seen that the problem might be in the helmet nodejs module i have tried to fix it with almost every answer related to this topic but still gives me this problem down here you can find the code.

```
const express = require('express');
const helmet = require('helmet');
const cors = require('cors');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
const config = require('./config');
const passport = require('passport');

app.use(helmet())
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(
    require('express-session')({
      secret: require('./config.json').app.secretKey,
      resave: false,
      saveUninitialized: true,
      cookie: {
        secure: false,
        maxAge: 60 * 60 * 1000 * 24 * 365,
      },
    })
  );
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
passport.use(require('./service/passport'));

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'views')));

app.use('/', require('./api/views'));
app.use('/auth', require('./api/auth'));
app.use('/answer', require('./api/answer'));
app.use('/user', require('./api/views/user.view'));
app.use('/courses', require('./api/views/courses.view'));
app.use('/question', require('./api/views/question.view'));
app.use('/answer', require('./api/views/answer.view'));


app.use('/api/user', require('./api/user'));
app.use('/api/course', require('./api/course'));
app.use('/api/feedback', require('./api/feedback'));
app.use('/api/help', require('./api/help'));
app.use('/api/questions', require('./api/question'));

app.listen(config.app.port,()=>{
    console.log('Server started on port: '+config.app.port);
});
```

Comment: What do yuo mean configure a domain to redirect to an IP address? Did you added an `A` or a `CNAME` record or what else?

Comment: I am using a URL Redirect Record, i am new to this so i don't know what i should do to make my domain point my web server ip address and leave the browser search bar with the domain instead of my ip address (i am using namecheap if this can help you answer my question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start trying to configure the DNS properly.

1. Add an `A` record to your domain (`1.2.3.4` to `your_domain.com`)
2. Add a `CNAME` record for `www` subdomain (`www.your_domain.com` to `your_domain.com`)
3. Add any other `CNAME` record for all required subdomains.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am going to try this as soon as i see that it works (it may take 1 day to see this) i will give you the points.

Comment: 10 years ago changing dns setting was taking 1 day to propagate, today is almost instant @AndreaDattero :)

Comment: Ok at the moment is not working, i dont know, i setted an A Record with host @, value my server ip address and TTL automatic and a CNAME record with host www, value my domain name, and TTL automatic am i doing something wrong here? I am sorry, i am really new to this world.

Comment: Which is the domain @AndreaDattero ?

Comment: don't worry you fixed the problem with your answer i just had to wait 30 minutes to see the update to my website in 8 hours i am going to give you the +50 reputation you deserve.

Comment: Well! That's really a great news! Thank you for the bounty. Could I also ask you to kindly accept my answer?